# Receive only a part of the datagram (UDP Sockets)

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

I am currently using UDP sockets in my C# Application and i expect to receive a datagram with 12 Bytes (header) + ? Bytes data. The data lenght would be given in the header. Functions like:

```
m_CommandSocket.ReceiveFrom(bheader, 0, 12, SocketFlags.None, ref CommandEP);
```

work fine when you have exactly 12 Byte. But when i start to receive actual data i get an exception that tells that my buffer is to small. I thought therefore i would give the index + lenght? If that does not work as i tried to use it whats the point in using it anyway over something like receive which gives an exact byte array. The whole point of this btw. is performance since i have to define the buffer first.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: UDP datagrams are packet-based. You either receive the whole packet, or nothing at all. You need to have a buffer big enough to contain the maximum sized packet (header and data) and use that buffer and its size. Then you have to parse out the header to see if there's data and how big it is (assuming that's in the header).

Comment: If you are unsure of correct buffer size (don't know maximum size of data to expect) - use 65536, which should be enough for any UDP packet.

Comment: OK thanks :) it allready seemed like fixed Packages from what i read on serveral sites, but i just wanted confirmation.